# float bootstrap dropdown list above content and right side of the sidebar main menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I can't figure out how to move the dropdown list so that it gets positioned on the right side of my main menus. Please see this screenshot that I want to achieve. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwLxe.png

Here is the code

```
<div id="sidebar-left" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 hidden-lg">
    <ul class="nav main-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="align-center">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span class="adClass hidden-xs">Menu 1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="align-center dropdown-toggle">
                <i class="fa fa-print"></i>
                <span class="adClass hidden-xs">Odometer</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a ng-click="stopIt($event, 'submenu1')">submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="stopIt($event, 'submenu2')">submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="stopIt($event, 'submenu3')">submenu3</a></li>
                <li><a ng-click="stopIt($event, 'submenu4')">submenu4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="align-center">
                <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i>
                <span class="adClass hidden-xs">Menu 2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="align-center">
                <i class="fa fa-flask"></i>
                <span class="adClass hidden-xs">Menu 3</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="align-center">
                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                <span class="adClass hidden-xs">Menu 4</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="align-center">
                <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                <span class="adClass hidden-xs">Menu 5</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="align-center">
                <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>
                <span class="adClass hidden-xs">Menu 6</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with whatever you have?

Comment: Ok, I'll do my best to recreate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap dropdowns use `position: absolute;` therefore you just need to move it left like:

`.dropdown-menu { left: 106px; }` just as much left as you need basically

Comment: That's what I actually did on my plunker( http://plnkr.co/edit/2cJGOes5mtF8OtsQJ82L?p=preview ) last night and it worked. However, on my real application, it didn't work. I kinda got it to work but I had to remove tons of "position:relative" and "z-index". Sorry if I didn't respond last night because I got shocked when my plunker wasn't affected. I started troubleshooting.

Comment: Finally got it to working by adding position : inherit 3 days of troubleshooting! This is good stuff!

Comment: will my simple answer wouldn't do what you are asking without to do tons of modifications?

Comment: Actually, I'm encountering some minor issues. I wanted the dropdown list to also move when I resize the browser. I got it working on the plunker by changing left to left : calc(100% + 20px). However, on my real application, it's giving me a real headache. When I put that code in, the dropdown list appear on the right. In order to position the dropdown to the left side, the code I wrote was calc(100% - 995px) and this is very weird and useless.

Comment: why don't you just use media queries with different left values? cal isn't even supported everywhere

Comment: I was thinking about that and call it a day but I'm not sure what media query I will use for ipads and forget about dynamic resizing on chrome on desktop. Correct?

Comment: i'd suggest you to use bootstrap for your html. You shouldn't be targetting for a specific device but rather a window size, as who says a user will use an android tablet rather than an ipad? Bootstrap has the grid sizes for all devices but anyway, my answer is what you need for what you asked

Comment: Yes rob.m, my code is using bootstrap 3 as the title says it. Although for this one, I was just checking if it's going to work while dynamically resizing browser. I'm sure when our qa tester resizes her browser and not use a real device, she might open a ticket. Look at one of the classes I put above, it's a responsive site class. :)

Comment: You question was how to place the dropdown menu on the right side of the menu and that's what I have answered, everything else is out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working but with the help of AngularJS. It's working great

```
var captureWidthOfSideBar = function() {
    $rootScope.widthSideBar = (document.getElementById('left-sidebarId').offsetWidth + 10).toString() + "px";
};
captureWidthOfSideBar();

var resizeTimeout;
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (resizeTimeout) {
        $timeout.cancel(resizeTimeout);
    }

    resizeTimeout = $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            captureWidthOfSideBar();
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

then on my template, this is how it's called

```
<ul id="ddPrinterAnalytics" class="dropdown-menu" ng-style="{left : $root.widthSideBar}">
    <li><a ng-click="stopIt($event, 'main.odometer')">Odometers</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="stopIt($event, 'login')">Real Time Print Job</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Battery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Printhead</a></li>
</ul>
```

WOOHOO!!! :)